# ICS crashes when intent.getExtras() is called

Tags: android, exception, crash, android-intent, android-service

This happens only on *some* ICS devices.

What my app is doing is basically waiting for a Broadcast and then starting a service with an intent.

The intent has a bundle attached, that will be read out with

```
@Override
public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId) {
    sets = new SettingsClass(this);
    Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
```

However, on some ICS devices that leads to this stacktrace:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start service de.bulling.smstalk.Services.TTS@418218f8 with null: java.lang.NullPointerException
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleServiceArgs(ActivityThread.java:2375)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1900(ActivityThread.java:122)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1209)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4340)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
at de.bulling.smstalk.Services.TTS.onStart(TTS.java:48)
at android.app.Service.onStartCommand(Service.java:438)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleServiceArgs(ActivityThread.java:2358)
... 10 more
java.lang.NullPointerException
at de.bulling.smstalk.Services.TTS.onStart(TTS.java:48)
at android.app.Service.onStartCommand(Service.java:438)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleServiceArgs(ActivityThread.java:2358)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1900(ActivityThread.java:122)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1209)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4340)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

The mentioned line 48 *is* the line where the extras are read. The same exception was issued with another service I used to call like this.

So now the question: How can I solve this problem? Is there another way of starting a service and passing it data or do I call the `getExtras()` in the wrong place?

Thanks!

Comment: have you checked in debug that the intent variable is not null?  I don't know why it would be, but maybe that is causing the issues.

Comment: Well, that seems to be the problem here (otherwise I would not have that nasty exception). But the Service does not start itself (or maybe is it restarted on ICS?), it is only started from the receiver.
However, I cannot reproduce this issue on anICS emulator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like that onStart might be [deprecated](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html), have you tried the method

```
@Override

public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId)
```

Comment: DAMN! I did not know that onStart is deprecated! Thanks a lot!

Comment: my pleasure, also the onStart() for activities is still very much in use, so can get a bit confusing :)